# Up-down control negative value

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, negative-number, numericupdown

How to programmatically get Minimum -0.5 negative double value with NumericUpDown, for example in range from -0.5 to 0.5 like this -0.5, -0.4, -0.3, -0.2, -0.1, 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5  with increment `numericUpDown2.Increment = 0.1m;` to initialize as value and make it available for spin box which starts from 0.0. or in case of property setting Minimum -0.5, just switches between -0.5 and 0.5

So `Convert.ToDecimal(-0.5);` does not makes sense for double to decimal

```
numericUpDown2.Maximum = 0.5; 
numericUpDown2.Minimum = // -0.5;
```

and same with  `numericUpDown2.Minimum = double.MinValue;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the minimum/Maximum is correct as your code is. You are missing two other properties to get the desired behavior. You also need to set the `Increment` value and the `DecimalPlaces` value like below. "M" indicates a decimal value. Hope this helps.

```
numericUpDown1.Increment = 0.1M;
numericUpDown1.DecimalPlaces = 1;
numericUpDown1.Minimum = -0.5M;
numericUpDown1.Maximum = 0.5M;
```